# Is there a way to get a `git diff`, but only include commits from a specified committer?

Tags: git

I have code base that is littered with code that does not conform to the predominate style and it is all perpetrated by one developer. So I have the commit hash of where it all began and I can get a massive diff of everyone's changes with it:

```
git diff f997d97b6ab6c9c0a38e793f8350360e85b08f4b
```

But now I want to be able to restrict it to only pull out diffs for commits that a certain developer has created. I have tried:

```
git diff --committer=example@example.org f997d97b6ab6c9c0a38e793f8350360e85b08f4b
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

So what is the accepted way of achieving this?

Comment: How do you expect a diff to look if you skip intermediate changes by others?

Comment: @larsmans good point however. I am not saying it should exclude the commits by others whilst calculating the diff, but just hide them from the display and only show me the lines I am interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`git log -p --author=Name`

Comment: The full command worked out to be `git log -p --author="Name Surname" f997d97b6ab6c9c0a38e793f8350360e85b08f4b..` to get everything from the specified commit to `HEAD`. Thanks for your help.